# Drawing circles with D3 from TSV file

Tags: d3.js

In the following code I'm giving my circle cx and cy values from a tsv file. But when looking at the code in the console the circles are not getting cx and cy values. In the browser the circles are all bunched up at the upper left corner of the svg. How do I assign the cx and cy values?

```
function makeDemo1() {
    d3.tsv("data/examples-demo1.tsv")
        .then(function(data) {
        d3.select("svg")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d["x"] })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d["y"] });
    });
}
```

The body

```
<body onload="makeDemo1()">
    <svg id="demo1" width="500" height="350" style="background: lightgrey">
    </svg>
</body>
```

The tsv file

```
x   y
50  25
150 100
250 175
350 250
450 325
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your circles are ending up in the top left corner, it means your data wasn't read correctly and the `x` and `y` properties weren't defined.
Are you sure your tsv file is tab-separated and tab-only? When it contains spaces, it won't work.

A working plunker, I changed nothing in your code, just making sure the data was tab-separated:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0YWmLKqkzWJ32w8Z

Comment: Thanks Sietse! Even after triple checking my file was tab separated it still would not work. I downloaded yours off of plnkr and it worked.